# Angular service not passing between controllers

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two controllers on a parallel scope level I need to pass data between:

```
function TableRowCtrl($scope, $http, sharedProperties) {
  console.log(sharedProperties.getProperty());
  $scope.items = sharedProperties.getProperty();
}
```

and

```
function SideNavCtrl($scope, $http, sharedProperties) {
  $scope.customers = undefined;
  var temp = "cats";

  $http.get('data/customers.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.customers = data;
    temp = "dogs";
    sharedProperties.setProperty(temp)
  });

  sharedProperties.setProperty(temp);
  console.log(sharedProperties.getProperty());
}
```

I am trying to use a service to do this (via examples I have seen) :

```
angular.module('myApp', []).service('sharedProperties', function() {
var property = "Cats";
return {
    getProperty: function() {
        return property;
    },
    setProperty: function(value) {
        property = value;
    }
};
});
```

However - when I try and set the data in the SideNavCtrl http success function, it does not bubble out - the service still returns 'cats' as its value. From what I have read, services are supposed to be global, and setting data in them should be permanent (as is its purpose). What am I doing wrong, and how can I get data between these two controllers on the same scope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your `TableRowCtrl` saves the result of a function in its scope variable. When the service itself changes, the value in the scope does not because at that point, it's a simple property. You can either expose your service directly in the scope or wrap $scope.items in a function instead:

```
function TableRowCtrl($scope, $http, sharedProperties) {
    $scope.items = function() { return sharedProperties.getProperty(); };
}

// And in your view
{{ items() }}
```

Or

```
function TableRowCtrl($scope, $http, sharedProperties) {
    $scope.shared = sharedProperties;
}

// And in your view
{{ shared.getProperties() }}
```

**Edit:** [Simple plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KYlBFtABJgiRpePEWAob)

**Edit #2:**

If the problem is a binding that isn't updated because of an asynchronous process, you can use `$scope.$apply`:

```
$http.get('data/customers.json').success(function(data) {
  $scope.customers = data;
  temp = "dogs";
  sharedProperties.setProperty(temp)

  if(!$scope.$$phase)
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

**Edit 3:**

I've recreated your `$http.get` and updated the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KYlBFtABJgiRpePEWAob) and it works. Based on what you are showing in your questions, it should work using function instead of regular properties.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something - after wrapping it in a function, I am still at the same error - the value being set by shareProperties in the http success function is not sticking. After trying these solution, I am still cannot get that data out and sticking to the service variable. It still looks as though the original value is staying, not the one being put by the setter.

Comment: @CharlesLillo I'll reproduce in a JS Fiddle in a bit

Comment: The example helps, but still doesn't address my problem I'm afraid -if you wrap your setter in an HTTP success function, the value 'Dogs' does not stay, and will remain 'Cats'. My issue is primarily concerned with being able to set and pass data in an HTTP success function.

Comment: See my second edit. When you run think asynchronously, you might sometimes need to manually apply the changes to the scope. Even though the $http and $timeout services are supposed to do that for you (I think).

Comment: Even if forced to run synchronously, I'm still having trouble (even with applying the changes to scope). I can set my $scope.customers and have those changes remain - but sharedProperties.setProperty does not last when inside that http function. If outside, its fine, but I need to use the data being returned by the http service and pass it to another controller.

Comment: @CharlesLillo I can't see why it wouldn't work. Can you create a plunkr with the $http call (you can add a json file to a plunkr to simulate, I believe) ?

Comment: @CharlesLillo I've updated my plunkr with an $http.get call and it works. See my edit.

Comment: The buttons do not seem to change the html on my end @SimonBelanger

Comment: @CharlesLillo I removed the function in the scope to concentrate on the $http.get call. I'll update and put the functionality back.

Answer (score 0):

@SimomBelanger already identified the problem.  I suggest using objects rather than primitives, then you don't need to call functions in your view:

```
<div ng-controller="TableRowCtrl">items={{items.property}}</div>
<div ng-controller="SideNavCtrl">customers={{customers}}</div>
```

```
app.service('sharedProperties', function () {
    var obj = {
        property: "Cats"
    };
    return {
        getObj: function () {
            return obj;
        },
        setObjProperty: function (value) {
            obj.property = value;
        }
    };
});

function SideNavCtrl($scope, $timeout, sharedProperties) {
    $scope.customers = undefined;
    var temp = "cats";
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.customers = 'some data';
        temp = "dogs";
        sharedProperties.setObjProperty(temp);
    }, 2000);
    sharedProperties.setObjProperty(temp);
}

function TableRowCtrl($scope, $http, sharedProperties) {
    $scope.items = sharedProperties.getObj();
}
```

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/3xekK/)</kbd>

In the fiddle I use $timeout to simulate an $http response.

Because getObj() returns a (reference to an) object, updates to that object are automatically picked up by the view.